# Enable WiFi on Ubuntu 12.04 Lenovo Thinkpad E440

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I have Lenovo Thinkpad E440. Just now I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Problem is Wifi is not enabled on this Ubuntu, only wired internet is enabled.

So please help me how to enable Wifi on this version of Ubuntu?

Following is the ouput of lshw -c network. Please somebody help me.

```
*-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 10
   serial: 68:f7:28:2a:0e:0b
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 ip=192.168.2.57 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:43 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:f0d04000-f0d04fff memory:f0d00000-f0d03fff
*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f0c00000-f0c03fff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

Comment: Please add the result of `lshw -c net` to your question

Answer (score 0):

What does a `rfkill list` shows?
If the wifi interface is in soft blocked state, you could try a `sudo rfkill unblock all` or `sudo rfkill unblock <device name>`.

Answer (score 0):

Network UNCLAIMED means there is no driver available for your device and since it is a new install, I would like you to install the updates and reboot

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If `lshw -c net` still shows "Network UNCLAIMED" after that then we can install backports, enter one line at a time into terminal

```
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.18.1/backports-3.18.1-1.tar.xz
tar -xf backports-3.18.1-1.tar.xz
cd ~/backports-3.18.1-1
make defconfig-rtlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot and see if wifi functions